# How to transform the whole /tf frame?

Tags: ros, learning-tf, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Given I have an occupancy grid map which I would want to transform with a certain [tx,ty,theta] transformation. How do I do it? The tf tree is posted below and also the rviz which contains the grid map. My ultimate goal is that I would have two occupancy grid maps which I would have to apply a transformation to either one of them so that they can be overlapped -- Map Merging. I'm looking for the mechanism in ROS where I can transform the map, particularly the whole /tf frame so that even the robot's pose will be transformed into a new coordinate frame.

http://postimg.org/image/d4xd3d39p/

http://postimg.org/image/vrdqce6x9/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/167686/how-to-transform-the-whole-/tf-frame?/) by [Xegara](https://answers.ros.org/users/14401/xegara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2014-05-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xuningy](https://answers.ros.org/users/18591/xuningy/) on 2014-05-28**:
Hi Xegara, I am looking at your /tf frames in the first image, and I am wondering how you were able to link /camera_link to /map? What launch files did you use to connect octomap and rgbdslam? Are you able to share what code in the .launch file (or your method of connecting the two and projecting the map?) Thank you.

**Comment by [Xegara](https://answers.ros.org/users/14401/xegara/) on 2014-06-21**:
You can run the following commands:
roscore
roslaunch rgbdslam slow_computer.launch
roslaunch rgbdslam octomap_server.launch
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch

The rgbdslam node itself also creates the tf tree I uploaded in the first image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can add a new tf frame with an offset from any existing frame to represent your new coodinate frame, and put the new map in that frame, transforming any objects into that coordinate frame first.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0